# If 'editor' is empty, then

Tags: php, conditional-tags

Is there a way to write a php conditional in WordPress that says:

`"If 'editor' is not filled out (i.e. empty), then, do some code..."`

I know it's sort of a strange request but basically I have a portfolio set up where if I don't fill out the editor for a post (i.e. project), I don't want a certain link to show.

Comment: Are you talking about the post editor field or the property `$post->post_content`?

Comment: @toscho I'm referring to the post editor field in the dashboard where I write the posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using something of the sorts for delivering some standard default text if the post content is empty. Give this a whirl:

```
<?php if( $post->post_content != "" ) {
    //do something or show content
} else {
    //do something else
}?>
```

Comment: Sure thing. Glad I could help :D